# can't add npm package to nuxt js [vue-star-rating]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, plugins, nuxt.js

I'm new in nuxt js so when I try to add npm packages it won't work these are trials.

**star-raing.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import StarsRatings from 'vue-star-rating'
Vue.use(StarsRatings)
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
    plugins: [{ src: '~/plugins/star-rating.js', mode: 'client' }],
    build: {
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    extend(config, ctx) {},
    transpile: ['star-rating']
  }
```

[it shows these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2FEz.png)

```
[Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This 
is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or 
missing <tbody>. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.


[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <stars-ratings> - did you register the component correctly? For         
recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Deals> at components/Home/Deals.vue
<Home> at pages/index.vue
<Nuxt>
<Default> at layouts/default.vue
<Root>
```

Comment: could you show us your home/deals.vue?

Comment: stars-ratings component is not registered. 
components: {
'star-rating', VueStarRating.default
}

Comment: Thanks for help 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should register it in your star-rating.js as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import StarsRating from 'vue-star-rating';

Vue.component('StarsRating', StarsRating);
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and here is the answer:

1. in your plugin (`star-rating.js`):

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueStarRating from 'vue-star-rating'
Vue.component('StarRating', VueStarRating)
```

> note: You have to create 'star-rating.js' in your 'plugin'
> folder

2. don't forget `mode:'client'` in your `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
plugins: [
{
    src: '~/plugins/star-rating.js', mode: 'client'
},
]
```

3. finally in your `.vue` file you can simply use :

```js
<star-rating v-model="rating">
</star-rating>
```

---

### ps: this is working for vuejs 2x

by the way if you want to get rating props you can simply access to it like this :

```js
export default {
    name:"example",
    data() {
        return {
            rating: 0,
        }
    },    
}
```

Comment: you mentioning about depreciated mode:

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-mode

please use ssr:false